# StackOverflowError When Calling RDD#toDS Using Java Object Instead of a Scala Case Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to use an existing domain object defined in a 3rd party library, namely, HAPI-FHIR's [`Patient`](http://hapifhir.io/apidocs-dstu3/org/hl7/fhir/dstu3/model/Patient.html) object to create a strongly typed Spark `DataSet[Patient]` like this:

```
scala> val patients = sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://mongodb/fhir.patients")))
patients: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD[org.bson.Document] = MongoRDD[0] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:47

scala> val patientsDataSet = patients.toDS[Patient](classOf[Patient])
```

But, when I make the RDD#toDS call above, I get a really long `StackOverflowError`.

The full stack trace is here: https://gist.github.com/vratnagiri-veriskhealth/6dcec9dbc6f74308019ab16c8d278a9b

Given the complexity of the domain object I've referenced above, I realize this might be a fools errand, but, given I'm a scala neophyte, I do want to make sure I'm not missing any simple tweaks that might get this working before I abandon this pursuit.

Here's part of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.ImmutableCollection.<init>(ImmutableCollection.java:48)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.ImmutableSet.<init>(ImmutableSet.java:396)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.ImmutableMapEntrySet.<init>(ImmutableMapEntrySet.java:35)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableMap$EntrySet.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:174)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableMap$EntrySet.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:174)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableMap.createEntrySet(RegularImmutableMap.java:170)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.ImmutableMap.entrySet(ImmutableMap.java:385)
  at org.spark-project.guava.collect.ImmutableMap.entrySet(ImmutableMap.java:61)
  at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeResolver.where(TypeResolver.java:97)
  at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeResolver.accordingTo(TypeResolver.java:65)
  at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.resolveType(TypeToken.java:266)
  at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeToken$1.getGenericReturnType(TypeToken.java:469)
  at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.Invokable.getReturnType(Invokable.java:109)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the schema before and after converting your RDD into a Dataset? Compare the schema and make sure that the schema is consistent with respect to the number of elements and their respective data types. The schema printed before the conversion and after the conversion must be identical.

Comment: The answer question box is only for complete answers to the question. This feels a bit more like a comment that is asking for clarification about the question. Either edit this to make it into a complete answer (presuming as to what the author intended), or delete this answer, wait until you have enough reputation and make it into a comment below the question.